# Why does this compound command {...} not exit on error, when used with ||?

Tags: bash, shell-script, set

I'm trying to run this script:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

{ 
    echo "Doing something"; 
    will_fail                 # like `false` 

    echo "Worked"; 
} || echo "Failed"
```

To my surprise, `will_fail` failed, but I did not see "Failed" on my command line, but "Worked".

Why did the compound command not exit with error after `will_fail` failed?

Comment: I can see both questions overlapping, but since my question focuses on compound commands and I don't understand the answer to my problem from reading the answers of the dupe, I feel both could stand on their own.

Comment: Reopened the question after substantial changes to the text of the question itself. It is no longer a dupe of the original `set -e` question.

Comment: @Kusalananda, I'm pretty sure there is a closer duplicate though. I remember seeing one quite recently.

Comment: See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105 or http://fvue.nl/wiki/Bash:_Error_handling

Comment: @Kusalananda, [Behavior of set -e in function calls](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/385532) is the on I had in mind (itself closed as duplicate).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas This question have an additional part in that it also asks about the exit status of a compound command.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Failed` will not be printed because the exit status of the compound command is that of the last command executing in `{ ...; }`, which is `echo`. The `echo` succeeds, so the compound command exits with an exit status of zero.

The following would output three strings:

```
{ echo "Do something"; echo "Worked"; false; } || echo "Failed"
```

From [the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09):

> Unless otherwise stated, the exit status of a command shall be that of the last simple command executed by the command.

---

There are several things happening here (summary):

- You run with `set -e` active.  This will cause the shell to exit if any command returns a non-zero exit status (broadly speaking).  However, this does not apply here since the `will_fail` command is part of (compound command, which is part of) a `||` list (and not last in it).

  Again, from [the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set) (my emphasis):

  > The `-e` setting shall be ignored when executing the compound list following the `while`, `until`, `if`, or `elif` reserved word, a pipeline beginning with the `!` reserved word, or **any command** of an AND-OR list other than the last.
- The last simple command in the `||` list is `echo "Failed"`.  This is what determines the overall exit status of the compound command.  Since it executes successfully (and since `will_fail` will not cause the shell to exit), the status will be zero, which means that the other side of `||` won't be executed.

Comment: So my mistake is assuming, that the { ... } command list is treated as one command by the `||` command separator?

Comment: @Minix It _is_ treated as one command (a compound command), but `set -e` does not apply to the commands other than the last in a `||` list.

Comment: But wouldn't the return code of the compound command be >0 if one of the commands in its list returns >0, as seen in the first example?

Comment: @Minix No, the return code is that of the _last_ command in the list. Try with `{ echo "Hello"; echo "World"; false; } || echo "Mars"`.

Comment: Why do I not get "Hello World" in the first example, then? It looks like the return code of `false`, not of `echo "World"` is used, there. EDIT: Ok, your last edit is the crucial information for me. I see. So by making the whole thing an OR list, the compound command is no longer under the supervision of `-e`, except for its last command.

Comment: @Minix Because there, the shell exits at `false`. Remember, it is not part of a `||` list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66002/discussion-between-minix-and-kusalananda).

Answer (score 0):

I think that the *intro* to the accepted answer (although I `+1` ed for its thoroughness) is misleading and it does not explain this exact issue in the presence of `set -e`. The rest below the line contains the answer. I decided to write it because I myself came here for it and first got misled.

> Failed will not be printed because the exit status of the compound command is that of the last command executing in { ...; }, which is echo. The echo succeeds, so the compound command exits with an exit status of zero.

What I think should be conveyed in the first place is that here, the `set -e` is disabled due to the *position* of the `{ ... }` in the AND-OR list. If one removes the  `|| echo "Failed"` part, the compound command in `{ ... }` will break immediately after the failing part, *not even reaching the last command of `{ ... }`*

Compare

```bsh
#!/bin/bash -e

{ 
    echo "Doing something"; 
    false
    echo "Worked"; 
}
```

prints nothing after `Doing something` and returns error exit, despite (here's why the answer is wrong) being a compound command inside of `{ ... }` with `echo` being last.

While

```bsh
#!/bin/bash -e

{ 
    echo "Doing something"; 
    false
    echo "Worked"; 
} || echo "Failed"
```

prints `Worked` after `Doing something`, does not invoke `echo "Failed"` and returns 0 exit status.

**The reason** is buried in the citation (provided deeper by the accepted answer): the `set -e` is **disabled** inside anything which is part of AND-OR command.

With trailing  `|| echo "Failed"`, the `{...}` becomes part of AND-OR command and hence stops obeying `set -e`. The `false` in the middle does not affect the flow, and proceeds to `echo "Worked"`, it returns 0 to the AND-OR, and subsequently to the calling script.

Without trailing  `|| echo "Failed"`, the `{ ... }` is itself a normal compound set of commands, it does not belong to the exceptions mentioned in POSIX, and obeys `set -e`. The execution stops when `false` is reached, and the flow of execution does not even reach `echo "Worked"` part, returning error to the calling script.